# Cross Platform Video streaming

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm looking for a video streaming soluiton which has the ability to upload the video  ﬁles to the server and deliver to multiple receivers on-demand across the hardware and software platforms (Desktop, Tablet, Mobile, Windows, Android, iOS, etc.). The solution should also support streaming live videos.

Can HTML-5 used as client for the above requirements? IF so, what should be the server side streaming solution? Any feedback and alternatives will be very helpful.

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [MediaMosa](http://www.mediamosa.org/), it is a backend that handles video management. You may create your own application on the front-end.